# Dynamically disable dropdown list value after form submission in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a drop down list and I can dynamically disable the value that was selected before.

But now I want the value to remain  disabled even after form submission. (Each and every value that the user selected in the dropdown list should remain disabled on and after form submission )  That is even when a different user access the page the value should remain disabled(greye-out)

```js
var $select = $("select");
      $select.on("change", function() {
      var selected = [];
      $.each($select, function(index, select) {
          if (select.value !== "") { selected.push(select.value); }
      });
     $("option").prop("disabled", false);
     for (var index in selected) { $('option[value="'+selected[index]+'"]').prop("disabled", true); }
```

```html
<select class="selectDate" name="category1" id="dateSlot" onchange="showData()" required="">
 <option value="" disabled selected>---Select Date---</option>
 <option value="Tuesday, 6 February 2018">Tuesday, 6 February 2018</option>
<option value="Wednesday, 7 February 2018">Tuesday, 7 February 2018</option>
<option value="Thursday, 8 February 2018">Tuesday, 8 February 2018</option>
 </select>
```

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript runs in the context of the current page and is completely removed from memory along with HTML and CSS when the browser navigates from one page to another after form submission. And the same applies to other users visiting the page.

You have persist the state to some storage (e.g. the database, or the local storage in the browser) in before the form submission, and read it before rendering the page to change the behavior accordingly.